# How to launch an application from another application on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to launch an installed package from my Android application. I assume that it is possible using `Intent`, but I didn't find a way of doing it. Is there a link, where to find the information?

but I want to open it in a fixed area of the layout not fill the layout is that possible ?

I wanna just open it in a part of the layout not all of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can launch another application by following code

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

see official link [for sending user to another application](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)

> but i want to open it in a fixed area of the layout not fill the lay
>   out is that possible ?

No that is not possible because you can call only `Activity` not part of `Activity`

Comment: Thank you sir but you dont know any way to open an other app in my own app without closing it ? !

Comment: No that is not possible in android

Comment: Thank you sir << i am sorry but i have more 2 questions please :
1-why when the url of the webview facebook.com it leave the app and open it in the Browser ?
2-why youtube videos does not work in webview when i run the app ?

Comment: for your first question your are launching link not native android application   so `facebook.com` is opeinig in webview

Comment: the problem is the link open in the browser not in my app ? 
what code should i write ?

Comment: For that you can   take `WebView` in your layout and then pass url to `WebView`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can launch another application (assuming you have the correct permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml). All you have to do is create the intent with the relevant [Action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (you can scroll down and see different type of Actions). And if needed, set the relevant "data" and then start an activity using that intent - android will know which application to launch based on the action.

An example that launches a phone dialer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:4087775555"));
startActivity(intent);
```

When you start a new Activity (launch another application) your applications moves to the background, so the answer to that second question is that no, you cannot "embed" another application in your application.

Comment: that's very good but i don't wanna open it i wanna open it in my app as part of its layout example : i opened my app then i pressed on calculator button then it opens the calculator in my own app not closing it or send it to the background .

Comment: @MahmoudMohsenSaad what you're looking for is an `iframe` behavior (borrowed from the HTML world). As far as I know - you cannot do it in Android.

Comment: okay thanks sir ,,,i am sorry but i have more 2 questions please : 1-why when the url of the webview facebook.com it leave the app and open it in the Browser ? 2-why youtube videos does not work in webview when i run the app ?